# what is the difference between these 2 javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I want to know what is the difference between **insideFn** and **outsideFn** in the follwoing case :

```
 function Construct()
 {       
   this.insideFn = function(obj){
   ....
   }
 }

 Construct.prototype.outsideFn = function(obj){
      ...
 }
```

and which one is efficient to use ?

Answer (score 5):

In the first case every instance created with `Construct` will have its own `insideFn`, which will waste memory in case you will use more than one instance. In the second case each instance of `Construct` will have just a reference to `outsideFn`. So the latter is better.

Comment: only wastes memory if there is more than one instance

Comment: There is also an upside to the first case: `insideFn` will have access to all the variables declared in `Construct`. That way, you can emulate private instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the first construct the method is an attribute of the instance of `Construct`.
In the second construct the method is an attribute of the `prototype` object from `Construct`

If you define functions inside the `prototype` object, they will be the same when calling.
The `prototype`variant often saves memory and speeds up the code.
You can also overload a `prototype` function within the instance of an object, to change the default behaviour of your object.

For better english and much more details see http://www.javascriptenlightenment.com/

Answer (score -1):

The first one `function Construct() {}` is a class(in javascript it is an object) whereas later on you are inheriting(extending) this class using the keyword `prototype` and adding one more function `outsideFn`. There are no specific classes in JavaScript so you have to use objects as classes.

Comment: -1: This is answer is confusing because it uses imprecise terminology (“class”, “inheriting”) and, while it does technically raise some applicable points, it does not explain the ramifications of these points.